# PHP plugin not working in intellij community edition 13.1

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I tried enabling it as mentioned [here](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/enabling-php-support.html#d1087190e347)

but nothing worked, any suggestion???

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because "Some features described here are available in Ultimate edition only." [(at the top of this page)](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/enabling-php-support.html)

[image]
(source: http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html )

Comment: The only "workaround" is to buy IntelliJ Ultimate (or PhpStorm if you only need php support). The community edition is not meant for web development.